# How to get xpaths,css selector for desktop application?

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i had an application which need to be automated using python selenium.The application is of desktop version(example :like whatsapp on desktop(windows OS) where u will run whats app on desktop(windows OS)) As we can get xpaths or Css using Chrome,Firefox or IE etc.
I want to know is there any tool or application that i can use to get the paths(xpaths,Css) for my Application so that i can get the paths and start automating the application.

Comment: weird thing is you are automating desktop application using selenium. thats cool.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check: Appium + WinAppDriver:

- https://github.com/microsoft/winappdriver

From documentation there is possibility to run native Windows Application:

- https://github.com/microsoft/winappdriver#classic-windows-app-testing

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never used anything like this, but a quick google search gave me this application:

https://www.inflectra.com/rapise/highlights/xpath-spy-tools.aspx

From the looks of it, you require a license, however you can sign up for a free trial if you're only doing a one off activity.